# How come every class in Ruby inherits from Object?

Tags: ruby

How come every class in Ruby inherits from Object even though you never have to specify that behavior?

You would expect something like:

```
class Foo < Object; end
```

but

```
class Foo; end
```

is enough. How does Ruby do this internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, when you define a class like this:

```
class Foo < Bar; end
```

Ruby (at least the MRI and Rubinius versions) calls a C method, very similar to this:

```
rb_define_class( "Foo", parent_class );
```

where `parent_class` is set to point to `Bar` (I don't know much about the C code that *finds* Bar from the bare name you specified, but that is not relevant to your question).

When you write

```
class Foo; end
```

Then the value of `parent_class` used is `rb_cObject`, which is pre-defined in the core of Ruby, and this reference is also attached to the `Object` constant, so it will find the same Ruby value if you specify `class Foo < Object`

Ultimately, this is just a standard *defaulting* mechanism, same as you might implement in a method definition. It is all defined in a similar way to using default values of any other parameter, just the syntax used to express it is different; deciding whether to use the default or accept your choice of base class is handled by the Ruby parser.

If you want to learn more about internals of Ruby - at least MRI Ruby and Rubinius - at this level, you could start with learning about C native extensions. [This PDF covers the basics very well](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf). The internal structure of MRI Ruby is actually a large and quite "flat" C API, which is relatively easy to code if you know only a little C. Rubinius is a bit different, but still presents the same API for compatibility with native extensions.

Comment: And if you want to know more than the basics: http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/

Comment: Great link, not seen that before, added to bookmarks!

Comment: I also found [this video](https://youtu.be/by5fFOBhtPQ?t=11m51s) on how it works internally. It shows nicely why every class inherits from Object.

Answer (score 3):

The question of how Ruby does this internally is not entirely meaningful since the specific mechanism is intentionally undocumented and could change with later releases despite the language spec staying the same. Additionally, there are many Ruby interpreters out there, and they could all implement this behavior differently.

For MRI, if you look at the source for [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-c-new) you'll see that if there are no arguments it sets the super to Object:

```
if (argc == 0) {
    super = rb_cObject;
}
```

[`rb_define_class`](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#modules-and-classes) from the C API works similarly (by passing `NULL` to `rb_define_class_id`):

```
if (!super) super = rb_cObject;
```

I have no idea which code path `class Foo; end` ends up taking, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -1):

This is by design of the language, vide `ri Object`:

```
Object is the default root of all Ruby objects.  Object inherits from
BasicObject which allows creating alternate object hierarchies.  Methods on
object are available to all classes unless explicitly overridden.
```

Comment: I know that it's by design, and that "Methods on
object are available to all classes unless explicitly overridden.", but the question is how does Ruby do that internally?

Comment: @charles: Oh I thought you meant "why?" by "how come?"  too . . . I think you need to clarify, because as it stands you are just asking about a very simple syntax construct (the *default* base class is Object, there's very little else to say - it's pretty normal to not need to specify a default, and not particularly interesting)

Comment: Well, it does it in the same way as the literal `10` is a Fixnum by default. I will repeat: by design.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific place in source code of MRI or other Ruby interpreter to find out how is the root of all objects set?

Comment: Yep, that would be great

Comment: Oh I see. I was confused with your question, you should ask more direct, like 'how Matz did it'. Sorry, I can't help.